# how to substite last occurrance of pattern in large file efficently

Tags: windows, bash, text, command-line, sed

Given a file with the following contents:

```
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
</root>
```

The command should output:

```
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
```

Things I've tried using the `GNU Win32` port of `sed`:

**Remove the last two lines.**

This is fast, but it assumes `</root>` is the second to last line and will cause a bug if it's not.

```
sed -e '$d' test.xml | sed -e '$d'
```

**Substituting all occurrences of `</root>` with an empty string.**

This works, but is slower than the first solution, and will break if there are nested `<root>` elements (unlikely).

```
sed -e 's|</root>||' test.xml
```

The file I'm dealing with can be large so **efficiency** is important.

Is there a way to limit sed substitution to the last occurrence in the file? Or is there some other utility that would be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Perl with File::Backwards should be very fast (relative, I know, but still...). Perlfaq5 has [a topic](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-delete-the-last-N-lines-from-a-file?) on going through a file backwards and removing lines. You can check for your pattern using this topic's code as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s|\(.*\)</root>\n\(.*\)|\1\2|'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `awk` for this.

#### AWK:

```
awk '/^<\/root>$/{next}/<\/root>/{sub(/<\/root>/,"");print;next}1' filename
```

***First*** `/pattern/{action}` statement looks for lines with **only** `</root>`. It pattern finds it, action ignores it.

***Second*** `/pattern/{action}` statement looks for lines containing `</root>` **anywhere** in the line. If pattern finds it, `sub function` replaces it with nothing and prints rest of the line.

***Third*** action which is `1` is true for all the lines that does not have pattern `</root>` in them. If it finds it, it prints it.

I did a quick test and this was the result -

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tmp
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
</root>
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
</root><root>
<a></a>
<b></b></root>
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/^<\/root>$/{next}/<\/root>/{sub(/<\/root>/,"");print;next}1' tmp
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
```

#### SED:

This should also work. Though it will remove all `</root>` and not just the last occurrence.

```
sed '/<\/root>/,$s///' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/<\/root>/,/<root>/{/<\/root>/{h;d};H;//{x;p};${x;s/[^\n]*\n//p};d}' file
```

This assumes that each `<root>` tag is matched with a closing `</root>` tag and that these tags occur on separate lines (as per the example).

Explanation:

1. Focus on lines between a closing `</root>` tag and an opening `<root>` tag or end-of-file.
2. If it is a closing `</root>` tag, save it in the hold space (HS) and then delete it and start a new cycle.
3. For all other lines within focus (see point 1) append them to the HS.
4. If it is and opening `<root>` tag, swap to the HS and print out its contents.
5. If it is the end-of-file i.e. between a `</root>` tag and last line of the file, swap to the HS, delete the first line i.e. the closing `</root>` tag and print the remainder.
6. For all lines within the focus, delete and start a new cycle.

An alternative solution with two passes:

```
sed -n '/<\/root>/=' file | sed -n '$s/$/d/p' | sed -f - file
```

Explanation:

1. Print out the line numbers of closing `</root>` tags
2. Generate a sed delete command from the last matched line number.
3. Pipe the command through to an instance of sed reading the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Use time function to see which one is efficient. sed should be efficient.

```
$time command
```

In my opinion, there is nothing which is faster than grep. try it with awk index() to see if it is any faster.